# How to return an error with Angular http if the data is html?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using Angular's http function to access my remote API service.

At the moment, my API service is offline, and if users try to access it, it still throws a 200 status which is 'ok' with Angular. Therefore, my success callback is always called instead of my error callback. Weird thing is, if I use a REST client, such as POSTman, it has a status of 404?

**Here is my function to call my API (using jQuerys `$.param()` function for URL friendly post parameters):**

```
$http({
  method: 'POST',
  url: "http://mydomain/api/login",
  data: $.param({
     username: "test",
     password: "test"
  }),
  headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
}).then(successCallback(response), errorCallback(response));
```

**Here is the response it gives when logged:**

```
{data: "
↵<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN…r at [my ip address] Port 80</address>↵</body></html>↵", status: 200, config: Object, statusText: "OK"}
```

**The response when the API is working is usually something along the lines of:**

```
{
  data: {
    id: 123
  },
  status: 200,
  config: object,
  statusText: 'ok'
}
```

Sure, theres a few dodgy things that I could do here such as writing a http interceptor to check if `data` is of type `object`, yet that's not really the answer I'm looking for here since some of my API calls just return a boolean value.

I also tried changing the 'Content-Type' to 'application/json', yet no luck.

I need my error callback to be used if my API is down. Is there an elegant solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

It all sounds a bit hacky, the most appropriate approach I can think of is to send a 404 / 500 from the API endpoints until it comes online.

Otherwise, try to set an `Accept` header:

```
{
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Accept': 'application/json'
}
```

Comment: Seems to kind of work. Yet it now looks like both the success and error callbacks are being called every time...

Comment: @Fizzix, well I knew I was good .. but.. try without the `Content-Type` header since it should be passed along anyway by angular

Comment: Still no luck, both the success and error callbacks are called each time. Weird...

Comment: Well, at this point I'd just go back to the original one and check for a string, assuming your api doesn't send strings usually `if (typeof data == String) { // is html string }` - or wait for someone more knowledgable ;)